# Why did Gandhari name her children with the prefix "dus"?

Tags: name, kauravas, gandhari

> Monier Williams
>
> दुस् ind. a prefix to nouns and rarely to verbs or adverbs (Pāṇ. 2-1, 6; 2, 18 , Vārtt. 2, Pat.; iii, 3, 126 &c. ) implying evil, bad, difficult, hard
> [Printed book page 488,2]
> badly, hardly; slight, inferior &c. (opp. to सु), often = Engl. in- or un- [ID=94676.1]
> दुस् [cf. √2. दुष्; Zd. dush-; Gk. δυσ-; Goth. tuz-; O.H.G. zur.] [ID=94676.15]
> It becomes दुर् (q.v.) before vowels and soft consonants; दू (q.v.) before र् and sometimes before द्, ध्, न्, which become ड्, ढ्, ण् [ID=94676.2]
> remains unchanged before त्, थ् (in older language however ष्ट्, ष्ठ्) [ID=94676.3]
> becomes दुष् (q.v.), rarely दुः before क्, ख्; प्, फ् [ID=94676.4]

Surely a mother would name her children after something good?

Comment: Duryodhana's another name was Suyodhana as well...

Comment: Lord vedavyasa was so unhappy with Suyodhana  named him as duryodhana meaning one have baddest wealth or wealth obtained by bad means.. similar dus sadhana.. one who have lowest of activity as his achievement.. like unrobe saree of uttama stree and also eleder brother wife and also rajaswala.. the 2 are Kali and their brothers who is lowest of lving being

Answer (score 2):

Are you specifically referring to Duryodhana and dushasana ?

Duryodhana comes from Dur + yogdhana literally meaning hard fighter.
Dushasana in sanskrit is spelled as दुःशासन, Duḥśāsana i.e., Duh + shasana meaning hard ruler/controller. See

https://www.indianetzone.com/3/dushasana.htm

I think the names were correct with prefixes of Dur or Duh meaning hard or tough.